# How to upload file into webservice

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, rest

How do I upload a file or image or video into a API REST service.

Do you have any tutorial, example or code.

Help me in understanding this concept.

Comment: What have you tried so far, do you have an example of your code, Have you tried Google to find a tutorial?

Comment: Some of the particulars will vary based upon the particular web service to which you're loading your image/video. Which service were you going to use (or are you writing your own, which is a whole other issue)?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with `NSURLConnection` or with `ASIHTTPRequest`,depending on how the webservice is made to accept the file.

You should offer more information about your problem so we know what to explain.

Comment: +1 Given that [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) is no longer actively supported, maybe something like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) might be a good alternative to [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: NSURLConnection is still easy if you understand the concept.

Comment: Agreed. Having said that, doing anything a little more complicated (e.g. you're trying to add a bunch of upload operations to a `NSOperationQueue`), it can be non-trivial with `NSURLConnection`, so a third-party library/framework can be helpful.

Comment: @Rob ASI is still useful on that queue part even if it's not the number one choice for many.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a file like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSMutableString *urlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"name=thefile&&filename=recording"];
[urlString appendFormat:@"%@", data];
NSData *postData = [urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding 
                                   allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSString *baseurl = @"https://www.yourWebAddress.com/yourServerScript.php"; 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:baseurl];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[urlRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
          forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
[connection start];

NSLog(@"Started!");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass Image on server then

```
 1) NSData *thumbData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgPhoto.image);
 Then convert this NSData into encodeBase64WithData, then Pass to the Server.
```

If you want to  Pass Video on Server then

```
 2) NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:YourVideoPath];
 Then convert this NSData into encodeBase64WithData, then Pass to the Server.
```

and You must remember that, You have to pass all data using @"POST" Method. Otherwise it load Long Url error.

Comment: (a) I'd suggest using the same `dataWithContentsOfFile` for images, too. Round-tripping image via `UIImagePNGRepresentation` can result in loss of information. (b) If you have to Base64-encode the data, you can do that, but some services do not require that; it depends upon the web service you're using.

Comment: I used ASIHTTPRequest And this is the only for ASIHTTPRequest